# ¿ Que configuración y/o permisos debo agregar a mi app en flutter que usa sms para que playstore/appstore la acepte

Tags: android, flutter, ios

Resulta que realicé una app que cuando se compila para Android utiliza el paquete sms_advanced, el cual permite enviar sms en segundo plano, desde la app presiono un botón y se envía un sms, esta característica no se puede tal cual en IOS entonces opté por usar el package url_launcher para abrir la app de mensajería. Todo en desarrollo me funciona muy bien, pero en las tiendas playstore y appstore me rechazan la aplicación y no entiendo por qué, me dicen que violo la política de privacidad. De pronto alguien me podría guiar en qué debo agregar a mi app en cuestión de permisos para que no la rechacen, he agregado los permisos en android, los que se adjuntan en la imagen[image: permisos android] y ya para IOS soo agregué el permiso de http y https que pide el url_launcher.

Quedo atento.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: podrías agregar los mensajes que te envían los del playstore y appstore

Answer (score 0):

Los permisos que indicas:

```
READ_SMS
RECEIVE_SMS
SEND_SMS
```

**son actualmente permisos sensibles o de alto riesgo y además por privacidad no son aceptados, si los deseas usar puedes [Declarar permisos de una aplicación](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102) en Google Play pero debes llenar el formulario de declaración de permisos y estos sean aprobados por Google Play**.

Debes tener cuidado de hacer correcto uso de la información de otra forma pueden eliminar tu aplicación de la tienda, recuerdo una caso de una aplicación que obtenía la información de los SMS (usando el permiso `READ_SMS`) y enviaba esta información a un servidor lo cual no es aceptado por Google ni por Apple.

---

Las alternativas que sugiere `Google Play` en este caso y que pueden aplicar en `App Store` son:

**Uso: OTP y verificación de cuenta por SMS**

**Alternativa:** Con la API SMS Retriever, puedes verificar a los usuarios de tu aplicación mediante SMS de forma automática sin que tengan que introducir los códigos de verificación de forma manual y sin la necesidad de solicitar permisos de la aplicación adicionales. Si no puedes usar la API SMS Retriever en tu aplicación, los usuarios pueden introducir un código de verificación de forma manual.

**Uso: Redactar un SMS**

**Alternativa:** Con el intent de SMS, tus aplicaciones pueden redactar un mensaje de texto SMS o MMS.

**Uso: Compartir contenido**

**Alternativa:** Con el intent para compartir datos, los usuarios pueden usar tu aplicación para compartir contenido o enviar invitaciones a través de distintas aplicaciones compatibles sin la necesidad de solicitar permisos sensibles de la aplicación.

**Uso: Iniciar una llamada telefónica**

**Alternativa:** Con el intent para marcar, tu aplicación puede encontrar el número de teléfono que quieras y abrir la aplicación. De esta manera, el usuario puede iniciar la llamada.
El intent para marcar no requiere el permiso CALL_PHONE.